# Performance testing with karate Mock

Tags: karate

I am running a karate mock service on kubernetes and with replicaSet set to 10 repliacas to handle the load of the request i'm sending to the mocks. some request go through and some fail with the error message of `Connection refused (Connection refused)`. i just wanted find out if i can increase the threads so it can handle the load of about 70 to 80 tps. is there a way of increasing performance or threads with the use of `java -jar karate-0.9.4 -m feature -p8000` or configuration file

Comment: apologies for closing as duplicate, but it is indeed a duplicate. hopefully you get some tips, and unfortunately that other asker did not contribute a PR, maybe you can